# KnockoutJS template ignores 'controlsDescendantBindings'

Tags: knockout.js, template-engine, knockout-2.0

I have a part of my template that I don't want to be rendered, so I have tried with "controlsDescendantBindings" [as the documentation proposes](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

I have done an example where the model contains two properties, "Parent" and "Child". Parent must be shown, but Child must be not rendered.

I am using the [KO Programmatic plugin](https://github.com/AdamPflug/Knockout.Programmatic).

It works neat with normal bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/QXJVb/

It works when using a template: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/uKLnm/3/

And it does not work when using KO programmatically: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/XGApK/

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your second and third fiddles are identical.

Comment: I have fix it, and it comes up that with normal templates it works, but with programmatic KO it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. You were using knockout 2.0 and jQuery tmpl. These don't play well together. Knockout has its own template engine built in since 2.0. jQuery tmpl is deprecated, and I think it also is no longer under development by its creators. You should not use it.
2. Your second fiddle didn't call `ko.applyBindings`, which is a necessary step. Your first one worked because you had that call.

Here is [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/uPVU8/1/), working with a template and a stop binding. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/uPVU8/3/) using the jQuery method

**Note**
Knockout provides its own method for limiting binding to specific divs. KO Programmatic looks kind of... unnecessary. Here is the snippet from [the documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example, ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

**Update:**

As promised, screenshot that these fiddles work as you describe.

the regular method:
[image: jsFiddle]

the jQuery/KO programmatic method:
[image]

Comment: 1. I forked another fiddle, that is why that file appears referenced. 2. They actually work, don't you see the Parent and Child property bound? It is just that is not honouring 'controlsDescendantBindings'. It is using a programmatic KO pluging.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. When I look at both the fiddles I posted, the HTML shows "parent" and nothing else. I can take a screenshot if you want me to.

Comment: If it shows Parent and nothing else means that it is working fine. If it shows Parent and Child, it means the binding is working, but it is not honouring the 'controlsDescendantBindings' option.

Comment: @NullOrEmpty please see my update. The fiddles I posted are working exactly as you describe. Parent is showing and nothing else. I don't understand how you are seeing another result. Are you sure you are looking at my fiddle and not yours?